# Limit at infinity existence

Tags: limits

My book says that a limit at infinity exists iff the limit as $x$ tends to $+\infty $ is the same as the limit as $x$ tends to $-\infty$.
And it also says that the limit as $x$ tends to infinity of  $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$  doesn't exist.
I do not understand the motivation of this definition. Please explain.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It depends on how you are defining ‘infinity’. It usually refers to positive infinity, I don’t see how the definition in your book is correct.

Comment: I think this would usually be called the limit as $|x|\to\infty$

Comment: please include the details of the book and where the definition is made.

Comment: Lectures on calculus (pratyush kr singh)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ is $1$, but it is $-1$ when $x$ tends to $-\infty$, so by the result given in your book, the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$ as $x$ tends to infinity doesn't exist.

The motivation is that one can think of "infinity" as an "extra point outside the real line", so that $+ \infty $ and $- \infty$ are identified with the same "point" but going in different directions. When you take the limit of a function tending to a point, if the limit exists, then it has to have the same value when you tend towards that point both from the right and from the left; this is the same intuition that one has to have with the limit tending to the "point" infinity.

Comment: I am asking what is the motivation of that definition.

Comment: See my new edit and let me know if it explains what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x=1$$ while $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x=-1.$$

So your book seems to define a concept of "limit at infinity", which is not the usual, one-sided limit at (positive) infinity.

You may think of it as the limit

$$\lim_{1/x\to0}$$ which differs from $$\lim_{1/x\to0^+}.$$

Comment: In order not to confuse the asker you should IMHO write 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x=1$$ in your first formula. It seems clear to me that in the OP's source a distinction is made with a one-point-compactification $\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ of the real line and a 2-point-compactification $\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$. At least this definition is compatible with the domain of the function being the 1-point-compactification whereas your explanation assumes the 2-point-compactification from calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Old-fashioned books may use the distinction between $\infty$, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

They might define limits so that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty,\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty,\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty
$$
and similarly define
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x),\qquad
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x),\qquad
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)
$$
I find such an approach uselessly complicated; it adds nothing to say that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$ except that there is an asymptote, but the function's behavior is better understood when one checks the limit from either side, in case the limit doesn't exist.

Similarly for the “limit at $\infty$”. It *could* make sense for algebraic functions, which can be seen in the projective plane, where there is just one point at infinity in each line.

Why doesn't the limit “at $\infty$” of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}/x$ does not exist? This is (a branch of) an algebraic curve, namely
$$
x^2y^2=1+x^2
$$
If we consider it in homogeneous coordinates, we get $x^2y^2-x^2z^2-z^4=0$. The improper points are when $z=0$, so they are $(1:0:0)$ and $(0:1:0)$. The curve meets the improper line at two points, which are, by the way, both singular points.

The tangents at $(1:0:0)$ can be computed as $y-z=0$ and $y+z=0$ (it's a simple node), corresponding in the standard plane to $y=1$ and $y=-1$. The other improper point is a cusp, with a single tangent.

This is why, in the terminology of your book, you have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$, namely the curve can reach the improper point only “along one asymptote”.

For the other improper point, the improper point can be reached “along two distinct asymptotes” and the chosen branch does exactly that.

[image]

[image]

Such an approach makes no sense when non algebraic curves are involved.